'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' error code when running js file using Slack API
I'm a bit new to this, but I followed the this Youtube tutorial on how to build a Slack Bot but I can't seem to make it work.
Here is my code,
For index.js
require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
module.exports = require("./app.js")

For app.js
import { RTMClient } from "@slack/rtm-api";
import { SLACK_0AUTH_TOKEN } from './constants.js';

const rtm = new RTMClient(SLACK_0AUTH_TOKEN); 

rtm.start().catch(console.error);

rtm.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Bot is now online');

});

For package.json
{
  "name": "slackapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Slack Bot Testing",
  "main": "src",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@slack/rtm-api": "^7.0.0",
    "@slack/web-api": "^7.3.1",
    "esm": "^3.2.25"
  }
}

I've found similar articles on using ES6 modules in Node12 but I am currently using Node Version18, and using import modules basically messes up some of my referencing.
UPDATE
Here is the full details of the error message
D:\Desktop\SlackAPI\node_modules\@slack\web-api\dist\WebClient.js:1
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\Desktop\SlackAPI\node_modules\axios\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Desktop\SlackAPI\node_modules\@slack\web-api\dist\WebClient.js:63:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Desktop\SlackAPI\node_modules\@slack\web-api\dist\index.js:22:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Desktop\SlackAPI\node_modules\@slack\rtm-api\dist\RTMClient.js:12:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Desktop\SlackAPI\node_modules\@slack\rtm-api\dist\index.js:5:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Desktop\SlackAPI\src\app.js:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Desktop\SlackAPI\src\index.js:4:18) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}


Please, list full error message including call stack

Hi @EstusFlask, updated my post with the full error message

There may be uses for "esm" but don't use it without a good reason, it's hacky and abandoned. The problem is that axios is a dep of slack\web-api and it's native module that's enforced with "type: module", which esm lib doesn't handle See https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/868#issuecomment-586705453 , it's not just v12 but anything after. Notice that the issue is not resolved. Stick to either using CJS with require(), or switch to es modules with "type: module" in your project and use only import, both should work
